# How to get journal or conference name after citation of the paper?

Tags: overleaf

I am using `\cite{chao2021gaitset}`, which provide [citation number] as:

[image],

I would like to get the journal or conference name of that paper as:

[image],

How may I get it?

Comment: Other than the fact that you use `\cite` to create a citation call-out, you have not provided any actionable information about your document setup. (And you haven't explained why writing "IEEE Transacdtions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence (2021)" after the `\cite` command isn't good enough.) I've noticed that you've set the `overleaf` tag; have you considered contacting the Overleaf Helpdesk directly? Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: sorry, I have not contacted to overleaf help desk, I will do it.